# How do I de-interlace a list in python

Tags: python, list

I come from tcl/tk, and am trying to do the following in python:

```
for a,b in [1,2,3,4,5,6]:
   print a,b
```

with the desired output

```
1,2
3,4
5,6
```

This is quite common in tcl/tk, but I can't figure out how to get python to do it.

Comment: Wow - thanks!!  Many ways to skin this cat.  I will have to do some research to figure out why some of these work   :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iter()` and `next()` functions.

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
it = iter(list)
for x in it:
   print (x, next(it))
```

Output:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
ls =[1,2,3,4,5,6]
a = ls[::2]
b = ls[1::2]

for i,j in zip(a,b) :
    print(i,j)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that.

Adjust the value of group_size to the number of elements you want for your tuples.

```
the_list =  [1,2,3,4,5,6]
group_size = 2
result = list(zip(*(iter(the_list),) * group_size))
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

And for your desired output:

```
for a,b in result:
    print(str(a) + "," + str(b))
```

Output:

```
1,2
3,4
5,6
```